# Кеш браузер http Нужно ли делать ресайз картинки?

Tags: http, изображения, браузер, кэширование

Пользователь загрузил аватарку, например весом 1 мб и разрешением 1024х786. Она отмасштабированная (200х200) показывается у него в профиле.

Этот пользователь написал много-много комментариев на одной странице и при показе комментов, возле каждого коммента, выводится его аватарка, то самое изображение, но уже в 75х75 пикс.

Будет ли браузер заново тянуть с сервера аватарку? или он возьмет ее из своего кеша?

Бывают разные ситуации?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

дак вы F12 в браузере откройте, откройте вкладку Сеть и посмотрите, что и сколько тянется. 
Масштабировать картинку лучше единожды при изначальной заливке ее пользователем, и создавать копии в разных нужных размерах. В вашем случае останется оригинал, и два варианта картинки 200x200 и 75x75.

Если на странице сайта вы будете показывать оригинал картинки масштабированный до нужных размеров с помощью атрибутов в виде

```
<img src="/img/user-1.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>
<img src="/img/user-1.jpg" width="75" height="75"/>
```

То картинка будет загружена только единожды. Вопрос в том, что размер этой одной картинки будет составлять все тот же 1 мегабайт, и если на странице будет 100 комментариев от разных пользователей, у каждого из которых аватар размер в 1Мбайт, то соответственно общий траффик будет 100 с небольшим Мбайт, что вряд ли может быть приемлемым для  странички с аватарками. Вопрос скорости загрузки и отображения такой страницы останется открытым.

Создав изначально копии изображений уже меньшего размера, вы уменьшите объем трафика в разы, а скорее в десятки раз.

Если для домашних пользователей безлимитный интернет в большинстве случаев уже стал обыденным, то в мобильной сфере траффик все также стоит денег.

Comment: копии картинки создавать как-то не кошерно :) про 1 мб - это я от фонаря написал. про f12 не подумал - но я проверю!

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy что тут не кошерного? всегда либо создаются различные копии нужных размеров и хранятся, либо картинки ресайзится при генерации страницы средствами языка программирования на стороне сервера. В первом случае проблемы возникают в случае, когда необходимо добавить новый размер, и приходится генерировать новые изображения для уже существующих оригиналов. Во втором случае каждый раз требуется тратить ресурсы на чтение больших файлов и их ресайз, поэтому обычно после первого такого ресайза такие изображения все равно сохраняются и запихиваются в какой нить кэш на сервере.

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy а на счет от фонаря, дак я счас переделывал сайт, там были логотипы которые отображались 120х75 где то, и показывались оригиналы. Один из оригиналов был 1.3Мбайт и размеров где то 1600-1200. Так что пользователь загрузить может что угодно.